# Actionscript 3.0 calling PHP function

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I´m aware that with

```
loader = new URLLoader();
loader.data;
```

it´s possible to get the entire data/information from a php page..
But I don't want a php page for every bit of information I want from to 'stream'.

So my Question is: Is it possible to have multiple functions/methods in a php script, and only call the method I require?

such as:

```
<?php
   function getColour1()
      echo "blue";

   function getColour2()
      echo "red";
?>
```

If "yes", 2 lines of code that show how, or  link to an example would be greatly appreciated.

cheers,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the page like this:

http://www.site.com/script.php?action=getColour1

Then in your code:

```
<?php

switch($_GET["action"]) {

    case "getColour1":
        getColour1();
        break;
    case "getColour2":
        getColour2();
        break;
    default:
        echo "Unknown action";
        break;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an "action" variable to PHP, then use if/else statements in PHP tp respond to that action.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the AMFPHP project: http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

It does what you're looking for

Comment: whoa. I don't doubt it works.. but i'm only starting off with Php and just want to push a few variables around.

Answer (score 1):

You want to hear about [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Moreover, you need to route your request to different functions - I advise you to use [this beautiful library](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php), if you don't want to go with a full framework MVC stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
$functionName = $_GET["action"];
$functionName() or call_user_func($functionName)
```